# Configure database connection in unit testing project's app.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I want to configure the visual studio unit test project so that it connects to my sql server database.

I tried to extract the connection string from my project's web.config file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and to use it inside the unit testing project's app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myConnection" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;"/>
</appSettings>
```

However the connection doesn't work, I would like to know how I can fix this.

Comment: how do you try to extract it? show us the code you use

Comment: Did you change connection string name? You shouldnt

Comment: Actually I have a web.config file that contains the connection string (first piece of code in my post) and I added it to my app.config file in the test project, this is what I mean by "extract"

Comment: Sorry this was just a typo @SirRufo

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question create the same 
    connectionStrings tag in the app.config it will work. Copying from 
    connectionStrings section of Web.config to App.Config 
    appSettings won't work.